# Proving a piecewise-defined map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$ is onto

Tags: functions, contest-math, integers

Let $F: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb N$ be defined by
$F(n) =
\begin{cases}
2x,  & x\ge 0 \\
-2x-1, & x\lt 0
\end{cases}
$.
Prove that $F$ is onto.

I Considered $y \in \mathbb N$. To find $x$ for which $F(x) =y$,
$y=2x$, $x=\frac{y}{2}$ and then $F(x)=y$
 and now I 
need to consider other  2 cases – $y$ even and $y$ odd. (stuck)

Can you help me out?

Comment: When $y$ is even, you found an $x\ge 0$ with $F(x)=y$. When $y$ is odd you can conclude there is no such $x\ge 0$. In this case, try to find an $x<0$ with $F(x)=y$.

Comment: You use the `contest-math` tag, what contest is it from?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=F(n)$. In the first case we have:
$$y=2n \leftrightarrow x=\frac{n}{2}$$
Because, $n\geq0$ and $y$ is even, then $n$ can vary in all naturals numbers.
Let $F(n)=2n+1$. Here we have:
$$n=-\frac{y+1}{2}$$
Because $y=-2n-1, n<0$, $y$ is odd so $n=-\frac{y+1}{2}$ varies in negative intgers numbers. 
In conclusion $F(n)$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

You write the first part of the answer yourself.

If $y$ is even, $y=2k$, then we use $x=k$ Since $y$ is positive, so is $k$
$$f(k)=2k=y$$

If $y$ is odd, $y=2k-1$, then we use $x=-k$. Since $y\geq1$, $k\geq1$ and $-k\leq-1$. $$f(-k)=-2(-k)-1=2k-1=y$$